# how to make relation between two tables in laravel

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-8

I tried all the tutorials on internet and Youtube but it doesn't work so you guys are my last chance please I need your help.

I need to use **$candidate->service->service_name**
and **$candidate->documents->doc** but it doesn't work
I get this error **[Call to undefined method stdClass::service()]** *(by the way, should I use"documents" or "document" ?)*

the "candidate" has more than one document, and the document belongs to only one "candidate";

the "candidate" has to choose one "service" (to work in) and the service is chosen by a lot of "candidate"

I have 3 tables :

> services=['id_service',
> 'service_name']  *#((id_service Primary key))*

> candidate =[ 'id_candidate',
> 'id_service',
> 'name',
> 'email'...];   *#((id_candidate Primary key, id_service Foreign key))*

> document=['id_doc',
> 'id_candidate',
> 'doc']   *#((id_doc Primary key, id_candidate Foreign key))*

IN CANDIDATE'S MODEL :

```
 use App\Models\Service;
 use App\Models\Document;
 public function documents()
{     
 return $this->hasMany(Document::class);
}
public function service()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Service::class);
}
```

IN DOCUMENT'S MODEL :

```
use App\Models\Candidate;
public function candidate()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Candidate::class, 'id_candidate', 'id_doc');
}
```

IN SERVICE'S MODEL :

```
use App\Models\Candidate;
public function candidates()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Candidate::class);
}
```

IN CANDIDATECONTROLLER :

```
public function show( $id_candidate)
{
    $candidate = DB::table('candidates')->select('id_candidate','id_service','name')->where('id_candidate', $id_candidate)->first();

    return view ('candidate.profile', compact('candidate'));
}
```

IN candidate/profile :
...

```
   <input type="text" id="service" name="service" value={{ $candidate->service()->service_name }}>
```

You're my hope
Thank you in advance

Comment: "_but it doesn't work_" _What_ doesn't work? How do you access the data?

Comment: i get this error [Call to undefined method stdClass::service()] @brombeer

Comment: Please share more details. Nothing in the given code calls that method

Comment: What about now ? @NicoHaase

Comment: The Eloquent relationships won't exist when you're doing `DB::` calls, because you're bypassing Eloquent doing that. You should be doing something like `$candidate = Candidate::find($id_candidate)`; you should also stop messing with the default structures. Laravel expects IDs to be `id`, not `id_candidate`.

Comment: Alright I'll try this, btw I'm just a beginner and I need to finish this project @ceejayoz

Comment: Good luck! Here's the [documenation on relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) in case you didn't know

Comment: @ceejayoz THANK YOU I had to do what you said and made a little change, I added the foreign key in this function : public function service()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Service::class, 'id_service');
    }

Answer (score 0):

Candidate Model

```
class Candidate extends Model
{
    public function candidate_documents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Document::class, 'id_candidate');
    }
    public function candidate_service()
    {
        return $this->BelongsTo(Service::class, 'id_service');
    }
}
```

By using DB::  relationships do not work as commented by @ceejayoz
so from candidate controller you can used it like this

```
$candidateResult= Candidate::with('candidate_documents')->with('candidate_service')->get();
```

you can also use hasOne in candidate_service() depends on where is your foreign key is
In your code, Candidate has a id_service column, then candidate belongsTo Service.

by using hasOne and hasMany we are telling laravel that this table does not have the foreign key.